# Let, $n$ be a positive integer such that every group of order $n$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Let, $n$ be a positive integer such that every group of order $n$ is cyclic. Then prove that for all prime numbers $p$, $p^2\nmid n$.

My attempts:

Let, $G$ be a group of order $n$ and $G$ is cyclic.
If $p^2$ divides $n$ for all prime $p$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^2$. Since $p^2|n$ so $\exists$ $n'$ such that $n=n'p^2$ and $gcd(n',p^2)=1$. So, $G=\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/n'\mathbb Z$. If $\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z= \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ then we can say that $G$ is not cyclic i.e. we can arrive at a contradiction. But oher case I can not arrive at a contradiction.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way I would solve it is just assume $n$ is divisible by $p^2$ and give an example of a non-cyclic group. You can do that easily by just considering direct products of small cyclic groups.

Comment: OK! Do you mean : If we take $n=8$, $2^2|8$ but the Dihedral group is not cyclic?

Comment: No I think I'd just use the example $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_{n/p^2}$

Comment: Yes, I get it thanks!

Comment: Your claim about $n'$ is incorrect; for example, if $n=27$, then there is a prime $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $n$ (namely, $p=3$), but there does not exist $n'$ such that $27=9n'$ with $\gcd(n',9)=1$.

Comment: To get $p^2\nmid n$ use `$p^2\nmid n$`

Comment: @saulspatz OK! done! Thank you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes yes. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this problem asks is that for such $n$ that is not square-free you devise a group of order $n$ that is not cyclic. Assume $n=p^{\ell}m$ where $\ell$ is an integer at least $2$, and $\gcd(p,m)=1$ and where $m$ may be $1$. Then the group $$\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \dots\times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}_{\ell \text{ factors}}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$$ [where the operation is component-wise addition] has order $p^{\ell}m=n$ and is not cyclic

Comment: Your  notation is ambiguous. Does the "$\ell$ times" mean that you have the product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ $\ell$ times (for a total of $2\ell$ factors)? Better to write $$\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}_{\ell\text{ factors}}$$(note "factors", not "times").

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin correct on both!